# How to tell if $f '(x)$ is increasing/monotonic/strictly increasing?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Suppose that $f(x)$ and $f ''(x)$ are continuous on the open interval $A$ and that $f(x)$ has no inflection point on $A$. Do we know if $f '(x)$ an increasing, monotonic, strictly increasing, or constant function on $A$?

I know that if $f '(x)$ and $f ''(x)$ are continuous, then $f '(x)$ exists for all $x$. If $f(x)$ has no inflection point on $A$, then $f '(x)$ will never equal to 0. However, if $f(x)$ is for example an exponential function, then it increases until infinity so $f '(x)$ will not be strictly increasing, but is it considered increasing or monotonic?

Comment: This is an interesting question with an interesting solution. You should give it a try. (-1)

Comment: Do you know that $f''(x)>0$? That is a sufficient condition, for example, to conclude that $f'(x)$ is increasing.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I just added what I thought of the question but I'm unable to find the answer.

Comment: @JWP_HTX the question did not state that f ''(x)>0, therefore I believe the solution is inconclusive based on the given. Do you agree?

Comment: To prove that it's inconclusive, you should come up with concrete counterexamples.

Comment: "If $f(x)$ has no inflection point, then $f'(x)$ will never equal to 0." Does $f(x) = x^2$ have an inflection point?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x^3 & x<0 
\\ 
0 & 0\le x\le 1 \\
(x-1)^3 & x>1
\end{cases}$$

The function does not have inflection points. Its derivative is not monotonic.